# Report with padded zeros cell shows as #VALUE! in Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a cell in a table that has its value set to an integer.

The `Format` of the cell is set to `000` which results in said integer being zero padded when displayed in the report viewer or other export formats (like PDF)

However, when I export this report to Excel, the value shown in the cells is `#VALUE!`.

**How can i have the value show as padded zeroes in Excel?**

I'd like to know if this can be done natively in SSRS design without embedded (.net) code or changing the SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can fix it;

```
=Right("000" & Fields!MyInt.Value.ToString, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

`#VALUE!` is shown when the value cannot be displayed in the cell. The format looks correct, so check that the column is wide enough to display the value.

Comment: widening the column does not change this display, and clicking on the cells reveals the value is indeed set to #VALUE!

Comment: That's odd. The formula bar should display the value as it is set, regardless of formatting. That implies that the value set in the sheet is *actually* "#VALUE!", which in turn implies that your query is broken. Can you verify that the query returns valid data?

Comment: when shown in the report viewer (or other export formats like PDF), the value is displayed correctly...

Answer (score 0):

#VALUE!  is shown when the wrong type of argument or operand is used in a formula.

Check to see that your data returned to Excel does not include a leading '=', '-' or '+'

If it does Excel will treat it as a formula.

If there is only #VALUE! in the cell, then SSRS is passing across a invalid value.

Also have a look the formatting in the cell to see what has been passed from SSRS.  I would expect to see a format of '000' or '000;000' or '000;000;000;'.

These are the formats, from left to right of Positive numbers, Negative numbers, Zeros and Text.